# Connection to MySQL issue

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I would like to make a connection between my program in VB.NET and my sql database. The code is like this:

```
 Public Function connecter()
    Dim Connexion As String = "Server=197.28.178.33;Database=test;Uid=userid;Pwd=xxxxxxxxxpassxxxx;"
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection

    conn.ConnectionString = Connexion
    conn.Open()
    Return conn
End Function
Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim lecteur As MySqlDataReader
    Dim Requete As String
    connecter.Close()
    connecter()
    Requete = "select * from article"
    Dim Commande As New MySqlCommand(Requete, connecter)
    lecteur = Commande.ExecuteReader
    Do While lecteur.Read
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(lecteur.GetString("description"))
    Loop
    connecter.Close()
End Sub
```

but this error appears:

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException'
>   occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Unable to connect to any of the specified
>   MySQL hosts.

what is the cause of this error?

Comment: Network connectivity issues. Firewall on the server? Can you otherwise communicate with the server? Is the server even running?

Comment: Do you realize that every time you write `connecter` you create and open a new connection object? Your code above creates 3 different MySqlConnection instances

Comment: @Steve I don't know how this code is even compiling, VB.NET requires parenthesis to be used for all function calls, VB6 was the last revision that didn't have the requirement.

Comment: @Dai Option Strict Off

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem and how I can verify if I communicate with the server? and How I'm sure that the server is running

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is the problem and how I can verify if I communicate with the server? and How I'm sure that the server is running